# Running a bash script from an HTML link or button

Tags: bash, html

I have a webserver that's hosting lots of images. I want the client to be able to press a button or a link, which will run a bash script, which will create a video based on all these pictures. The script I'm trying to run is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd to the directory
cd /var/www/gallery

# use ffmpeg to make video
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i 'img-*jpg' -r 1 video.mp4

# Take the first file in the directory and name it video.mp4.jpg (for thumbnail)
cp `ls | sort -n | head -1` video.mp4.jpg
```

The script is located on the server. So when the client clicks the link or button, the script will run, and the video is created. I've tried both solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button) but I can't seem to get it to work. I have php installed on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do serverside scripting in bash without problem.

Here a short tutorial how to do it: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html