# Link in HTML cannot execute .sh file

Tags: linux, bash, html

I have an `index.html` with a link which must remove all *.zip from `/mnt/sda1/down`.

When I click on the link it start to download not to execute the sh script.

Here is the `index.html` and the sh script :

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /mnt/sda1/down
rm *.zip
```

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label><a href="delete.sh">DELETE ALL</a>  </label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should have the script in a cgi executable directory for the server (e.g. cgi-bin), as well as have the script set to be executable generally. There may also be extra steps if you have SELinux on your system. This question has a link to a relevant tutorial - - https://superuser.com/q/670666/302907

Answer (score 0):

Your link is a link to a file that your browser doesn't recognize so it assumes it is is a download.

Putting that link in a `<form>` doesn't change anything. The purpose of the `<form>` element is to gather parameters before calling the URL specified in the "action" attribute (usually with an `<input type="submit">` element in the form).

It is not even clear that there is a server involved. If so what type is it?

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not have this power. What you need to use is PHP as it can interact with your OS since it is a backend language.

What you can do is create a link to a php file and when the link is clicked it will navigate to the PHP file, executing the script then you can tell it to redirect you back to the home page or something:

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="delete.php">DELETE ALL</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('sh /path/to/delete.sh');
header('Location: /'); #this will take you back to the home page
?>
```

Original Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php